# Self-answered question: Closed as off-topic before I could answer

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I recently posted my first question to SO, with the intent of answering it myself, but it was closed as off-topic before I could provide an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251625/installing-chrubuntu-on-usb-drive-to-run-on-acer-c7-chromebook

I suppose it's not strictly about programming, but rather about configuration of a machine for programming. I read through the etiquette, and learned before I posted that it was OK to self-answer. I could set up a personal blog to answer this, but thought it would be easier to post on SO.

I learned a bit about setting up Ubuntu on the Chromebook, and I think my answer could be of help to others in the same situation; but want to be sure it fits in the context of SO. Could you provide insight as to where to go from here?

Comment: Might be better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Find an appropriate site within the network (not sure that it exists for a question in that form) or externally. Just because you intend to self-answer the question doesn't mean it shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: For the future, if you want to ask and answer in one shot, check the checkbox under the question, and you can provide an answer at the same time.  We might very well still close the question, but at least you'll get your answer in.

Comment: @Eric Not [ubuntu.se]: that site is only for questions about official versions of Ubuntu, not third-party derivatives such as ChrUbuntu. Such a question would be on-topic on [su], or better [unix.se].

Comment: There is the issue with the quality of the question, aside from the topicality of the question on *this* site. It's a question that sounds contrived as a vehicle for the answer, rather than a real question.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the ideas. Clearly this kind of solution belongs elsewhere. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fact that you wanted to answer the question yourself is irrelevant.  The question is offtopic and as such will be closed, since it is asking a question outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.  Even if you had been able to get your answer in in time, the question should still be closed.

The fact that you want to self-answer a question doesn't lower the quality standards for asking a question.  The question needs to stand alone as an acceptable quality question to remain open on the site.

Comment: You say it, but I'd like to emphasize this: the fact that you wanted to self-answer does not make your question any less likely to be closed as off-topic (it also doesn't make it any more likely to be closed for this reason).

Comment: Yes, it is a little awkward to frame a question when I already know the answer. I was looking for a way to share the answer here; but apparently there are other, more appropriate places for me to post this.

Answer (score 2):

You did not try anything.

Also that type of question is **not** on topic for Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: _"with the intent of answering it myself"_ - perhaps the question/answer split was wrong

Comment: @Eric no tries shown = not answer worthy...

Comment: How else are you supposed to immediately answer your own question? Why make something up that failed to put in the question when you can just put the working solution in the answer?

Comment: @Eric: Even if he *didn't* have the answer, that question is still incredibly broad and would be closed as not a real question even on an appropriate site. The thing with self-answers is that you have to look at the question and answer *separately*. It's not an excuse to ask a terrible question.

Comment: @Eric That's the reason that self-answered questions tend to be of very low quality.  Most of the good ones are when there was some point in time where the answerer *didn't* know the answer, and they either wrote the question then (and didn't post it) or are a skilled enough writer/introspecter to write the question as the problem they once had, rather than some vague open ended something or other as a placeholder for the answer they care about.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you post that kind of questions to super user.

Then it doesn't matter if you've found the solution, the question itself is still off topic.